# Cпуск  по ступенькам

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!Как сделать чтобы координаты до которых поднялись, с этих координат опустится вниз?Вот текст программы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ступеньки </title>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
<p><H2>Это программа позволяет следить за координатами объекта который поднимается и спускается по ступенькам
<br>Высота каждой ступеньки равна фиксированной единице и равна=1<br>Шаг равен 3 </H2></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("мы рады видеть вас!спасибо что зашли в эту программу")
function f(obj)
{

var h=10*Math.random()+5
obj.s1.value=Math.round(h)
arrx=new Array()
arry=new Array()
x=0;x2=0
for(i=0;i<=h;i++){
 x=x+x2

y=i
arrx.push(x)
arry.push(y)
x2=Math.round(2*Math.random()+1)
x+x2
}
obj.s3.value=arrx
obj.s4.value=arry

} 
function f1(obj){
var h=10*Math.random()+5
obj.s1.value=Math.round(h)
arrx=new Array()
arry=new Array()
x=0;x2=0
for(i=0;i<=h;i++){
 x=x+x2

y=i
arrx.unshift(x)
arry.unshift(y)
x2=Math.round(2*Math.random()+1)
x+x2
}
obj.s3.value=arrx
obj.s4.value=arry

}

</script>
<form name="myform">
 количество ступенек<input type="text" name="s1" size=10  ><hr>

координаты X<input type="text" name="s3" size=60  ><hr>
координаты Y<input type="text" name="s4" size=60  ><hr>

<input type=button name="c"value=" поднимаемся" 
onclick="f(myform)">
<input type=button name="c"value=" спускаемся" 
onclick="f1(myform)">

<input type="reset"value="cброс">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Увидел цикл и не смотрел ничего больше.. Но думаю это то, что нужно.. А нужно цикл сделать вида:

```
for (var i = h; i >= 0; i--) {

}
```